How do we define the Hamiltonian for a QFT in curved space?
Suppose we have a scalar field theory described by an action
$$S[\phi] = \int_M d^{n+1}x \sqrt{|g|}L(\phi,\nabla_\mu \phi), \quad L(\phi,\nabla_\mu \phi) = \frac{1}{2} \nabla_\mu \phi \nabla^\mu \phi$$
on an $(n+1)$-dimensional curved spacetime $M$, where $\phi$ denotes the scalar field of the theory $g$ is the fixed background metric. Let us also assume the metric has time translation symmetry, allowing us to decompose spacetime as $M = \mathbb{R} \times \Sigma$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the time dimension and $\Sigma$ is a spatial hypersurface.
There appears to be two different ways to define the Hamiltonian and I do not know why you would choose one over another.
Method 1: Energy-momentum tensor and Killing vectors
The energy momentum tensor of the theory is given by
$$T^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} =  \nabla^\mu \phi \nabla^\nu \phi - \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\alpha \phi \nabla^\alpha \phi$$
and is covariantly conserved as $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu \nu} = 0$. Suppose we have a time-like Killing vector $K^\mu$, then we can define the current $j^\mu = T^\mu_{\ \nu} K^\nu$. Now, given the normal vector of the spatial hypersurface $n_\mu$, we can write down a conserved charge
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
H_1 & = \int_{\Sigma} d^nx \sqrt{|h|} T^\mu_{\ \nu} K^\nu n_\mu  \\
& \equiv \int_{\Sigma} d^nx \mathcal{H}_1
\end{aligned}
$$
where $h$ is the metric pulled back to $\Sigma$.
Method 2: Legendre transform
First I can trivially rewrite the action as
$$ S[\phi] = \int_M d^{n+1}x \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu \phi)$$
by absorbing the determinant into the Lagrangian as $\mathcal{L} = \sqrt{|g|}L$. This is just some Lagrangian, so I can transform to the Hamiltonian via a Legendre transform as
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
H_2 & = \int_\Sigma d^n x \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_t \phi)} \partial_t \phi - \mathcal{L}\right) \\
& = \int_\Sigma d^n x  \frac{\sqrt{|g|}}{2} \left( \nabla_t \phi \nabla^t \phi - \nabla_i \phi \nabla^i \phi \right) \\
& = \int_\Sigma d^n x  \sqrt{|h|} T^0_{\ 0} \\
& \equiv \int_{\Sigma} d^nx \mathcal{H}_2 
\end{aligned}
$$
which can be shown easily by using $\partial_\mu \phi = \nabla_\mu \phi$ for scalar fields. By applying Noether's theorem to time translation symmetry of this action, this is also a conserved charge.
My question
In general, these two Hamiltonians are different. If we have the time-like Killing vector $K^\mu = (1,0,0,\ldots)$ and the normal vector $n_\mu = (1/\sqrt{g^{tt}},0,0,\ldots)$ to the spatial hypersurfaces $\Sigma$, normalised so that $g^{\mu \nu} n_\mu n_\nu = 1$, we have
$$ \mathcal{H}_2 = \sqrt{g^{tt}} \mathcal{H}_1$$
If $g^{tt}$ is some complicated function of $x$ then these two Hamiltonians will be completely different.

What is the interpretation of these?
Why would I choose one over another?


It depends on which properties of a Hamiltonian are you based on. In the first procedure, You defined the Hamiltonian based on a conserved charge. We know that systems with time translational symmetry should conserve energy and we know that such charge is strongly related to the Hamiltonian of the system. So $\mathcal{H}_1$ is sharp defined to satisfy this property.
In the second definition, when we do a Legendre Transform, we are thinking about to preserve the solutions of the equation of motion, to obtain the correct canonical equations, in this case for the given field. So $\mathcal{H}_2$ is the correct Hamiltonian in this sense.
But then one can ask: which one is the correct one? First, look that, by your example with a time-like Killing Vector, both differs by a multiplication by a time function, which does not affect the canonical equations for the field. We can say that both give us the correct field equations, despite the first been the conserved charge. I'll rather say that for more complex Killing vectors this property should remain, but I can't prove it.
Another question is if the second Hamiltonian would always be the conserved charge associated with time translation symmetry. For this I think you can verify, but right now I would say no, and actually you kind of prove it.

Is the second Hamiltonian not the conserved charge due to $t$ translation by Noether's theorem? Regardless of how we interpret the $t$ coordinate, the action $S$ has $t$-translation symmetry under $\phi(t,x) \rightarrow  \tilde{\phi}(t,x) = \phi(t- \epsilon,x)$ for all $\epsilon$ so the Noether charge corresponding to this will be conserved.

But then this is strange and I'm missing something, since both Hamiltonians should be constant and they have different time dependence
